# What do you call a person who says sweet things about person to win his favors?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ok, I am not native English speaker. But in my language there is a word for a person who starts saying good things about you just to get you do what he wants.

It's kind of repulsive to be around such people. You know they don't mean it; they know you don't believe them. But they dare to keep stretching your qualities, and you know what they are coming to. To get you do something for them. In reality they hold no admiration for you, and disregard you as soon as they no longer need you. In fact, you are never sure if any word they speak is from heart, ever. You sometimes feel sorry for them, that their inner person is forever drowned in their lies, censored.

You would usually find these people with kings, who would be like you are the best.

Comment: Possible word could be suck-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **'Flatterer'**.

'boot-licker', 'sweet-talker', 'charmer', 'back-scratcher', 'fawner', 'flunkey'  etc. are some of the synonymns

Answer (score 2):

In English, there are many many words for such persons. Some of them are reasonably polite like sycophant, toady, adulator, suck-up and so on. However, these words do not describe them quite as well as certain other, but more unprintable words, such as a******s, @%&##, etc etc...

Comment: I've seen pimp used to describe such behavior.  I understand why it was used but wouldn't use it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is flatterer. There are other words as well, like coax, toady, and sycophant. The last two words imply in a submissive position